# SQL SERVER, Problemas con el total en columna y fila

Tags: sql-server-2008

Muy buenas comunidad,en este caso estoy desarrollando un pivote dinámico en sql server, pero tengo dificultades para obtener el total, por ello necesito obtener el total de los registros en obtenidos de forma vertical y horizontal como pueden ver en la imagen de mi salida.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@estado AS 
VARCHAR(1)='A',@tipo AS VARCHAR(1)='2'
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME(NOMPRO)
            FROM TABLAGENERAL
                 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                 ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                 ,1,1,'')

SET @query = '
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT DESC AS DESCRIPCION,NOMPRO AS PRO,HRS AS TOTAL FROM TABLAGENERAL
                       WHERE ESTADO='''+@estado+''' AND TIPO='''+@tipo+''' GROUP BY DESC,NOMPRO,HRS,PER,NOMMA
                       ) S
                PIVOT(
                       SUM(TOTAL)
                       FOR [PRO] IN ('+@cols+')
                ) P '
EXECUTE(@query);
```

**Actual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Salida deseada:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

YO USUARIA UN STORE PRECEDURE PARA HACER LA CONSULTA, CREARIA UNA TABLA TEMPORAL Y RETORNARIA CON LA ESTRUCTURA DE LOS DATOS A NECESITAR

AQUI EL EJEMPLO

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EJEMPLO

AS BEGIN

---TE RECOMIENDO USAR UN STORE PROCUDURE Y USAR EL USO DE TABLAS TEMPORALES
DECLARE @TABLA_DATOSORIGINAL TABLE ( 
    DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CAMPONUM INT,
    CAMPONUM2 INT
)

---ESTA TABLA REPRESENTA LA TABLA DONDE ESTAS OBTENIENDO TUS DATOS

INSERT INTO @TABLA_DATOSORIGINAL(DESCRIPCION, CAMPONUM, CAMPONUM2) VALUES ('EJEMPLO 1', 1,2)
INSERT INTO @TABLA_DATOSORIGINAL(DESCRIPCION, CAMPONUM, CAMPONUM2) VALUES ('EJEMPLO 2', 2,2)

DECLARE @TABLATEMP TABLE ( 
    DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CAMPONUM INT,
    CAMPONUM2 INT,
    TOTAL INT
)
---AQUI USARIAS EN VES DE VALUES UN SELECT LO QUE YA TIENES 
INSERT INTO @TABLATEMP (DESCRIPCION, CAMPONUM, CAMPONUM2, TOTAL) 
SELECT DESCRIPCION, CAMPONUM, CAMPONUM2, (CAMPONUM+CAMPONUM2) FROM @TABLA_DATOSORIGINAL

--LUEGO HACEMOS OTRO INSERT PERO EL DE LA SUMA DE TODAS LAS FILAS
INSERT INTO @TABLATEMP (DESCRIPCION, CAMPONUM, CAMPONUM2, TOTAL) 
SELECT 'TOTAL', SUM(CAMPONUM), SUM(CAMPONUM2), SUM(TOTAL) FROM @TABLATEMP

SELECT * FROM @TABLATEMP
END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]